# google検索結果に表示される日付のスニペットをcsvに落としたい

Tags: python, web-scraping

Python初心者です。
タイトルの通り、google検索結果に表示される日付のスニペットをcsvに出力したいと考えています。

https://arakan-pgm-ai.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/01/17/080000
上記のサイトのコードをそのままコピーさせていただいたところ、タイトル、リンク等は取得できたのですが、CSSセレクタの見方がよくわからず、日付の情報がうまく取得できません。

どなたか日付もcsvに出力するためのコードをご教示いただけないでしょうか。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。日付の情報だけをできれば抜き出したいんですが、その場合はどうしたらよいでしょうか？ Googleの検証ツール上だと<span.f>タグで指定できそうなのですが、全然違う箇所が抽出されてしまいました。

Answer (score 1):

単純に`soup.select('span.f')`とすると日付の情報も取れますが、それ以外の情報も含まれるし、タイトル、リンクとのマッチングができなくなります。

日付は、「検索結果の説明部分」にあるので、質問にあるサイトのコードでは、以下の「検索結果の説明部分を取得」のところで一緒に取れています。

```
# 検索結果のタイトルとリンクを取得
link_elem01 = soup.select('.r > a')
# 検索結果の説明部分を取得
link_elem02 = soup.select('.s > .st')
```

タイトル、リンクとマッチングさせたいのならば、コードの後半にある変数`i`を使ったループ内で`link_elem02[i]`から日付情報を取得する必要があります。

CSSセレクタの見方がよくわからないのであれば、日付はlink_elem02の先頭部分にあるので、先頭の何文字（設定によって表示が違ってくる）かを取って文字列の検索でも正規表現を使っても取得するようにしてください。

Answer (score 1):

CSSセレクタで
`.s > .st`
はsクラスの子要素であるstクラスを表しています。
さらにその子要素のfクラスであれば
`.s > .st > .f`
となります。